# Rendering HTML file with res.sendFile() in Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, express, static-files

I'm trying to render my HTML file with some a local CSS file, local JS file and two remote files as links

but all I got is a plain HTML in the browser

here is the top of my HTML file (index.html):

```
<script src="src/drawflow.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/index.css" />
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
```

This is my server code (app.js):

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/src"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 4000, () => {
  console.log("listening to port 4000...");
});
```

and here is my file structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqxci.png)

The index.html file is working just fine when opened in the browser but it can't be fetched properly from the server.

Any ideas ?

Comment: In your html file, you are trying to access your index.css from src/index.css. However in your app.js you are putting your index.css under the root. So your href would need to be href="index.css"

If you'd like this to be accessible from src/index.css then you will need to update your express static to be

app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/src'));

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by [Chris Short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5140389/chris-short)

I replaced

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/src"));
```

to

```
app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/src')));
```

and it worked perfectly.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly. The assets for your HTML file are not being fetched properly, so your HTML is showing as bare when you access through the browser. With this understanding, the reason your assets are not loading properly is due to the way your app.js is set up.

Currently you are trying to access `href="src/index.css"` in your header, however all of your assets are going to be found from your website root. Expressjs handles all `app.use` statements as middleware and by default are attached to the root of your website. If you would like to have this accessible from "src" then you will need to set up your express.static a bit differently like so.

```
app.use("/src", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/src"));
```

See the below for more info

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html